# Video como background no me aparece - 404 not found

Tags: html, video, src, background

Tengo un problema y es que cuando ejecuto el index.py en localhost la pagina me aparece todo bien pero no me muestra el fondo que es un video, si ejecuto el index.html si me toma el video y todo. Trate de ponerlo en una carpeta llamada video, trate adentro de templates, no hay caso, no me lo toma. Por cierto me sale asi en consola...

:5000/holaa.mp4:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

:5000/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Como ven tampoco me sale el icono de la ventana y las imagenes que tenia despues de h1 les tuve que poner url porque tampoco me salian, la cosa es que el video tampoco me lo toma como url

HTML

```
<body>
    <header class="header content">
        <div class="header-video">
            <video autoplay loop muted>
                <source src="holaa.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="header-overlay"></div>
        <div class="header-content">
            <h1>9.queens</h1>
            <a href="https://www.paypal.me/uliwolo"><img id="logopaypal" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Paypal_2014_logo.png" alt="paypal"></a>
            <a href="#"><img id="logomercadopago" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/792539/screenshots/2830556/mercadopago-01.png" alt="mercadopago"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/9.queens/"><img id="logoinstagram" src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/instagram-logo-6.png" alt="instagram"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

JS

```
function video_show() {
    $("#video video").each(function() {
        this.volume = 0.0;
    });

};

/*
function play_sound() {
    $("#video video").each(function(play_sound) {
        this.volume = 0.2;
    });

};

function mute_sound() {
    $("#video video").each(function(mute_sound) {
        this.volume = 0.0;
    });

};
```

*/
PD: no entiendo mucho recien estoy empezando, de todas formas, revise todo y nose porque pasa.

pondria una foto de los documentos pero nose como poner para que se vean en cascada o escalera

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente no estas referenciando correctamente el archivo de vídeo.

Antes de nada tienes que entender como funciona el "Path" o ruta para importar archivos.

Para que funcionara el código que mencionas, el archivo ( llamado holaa.mp4 ) deberia estar en la misma carpeta que el index.

Comment: lo hice, lo tengo en todas las carpetas el video pero de cualquier referencia posible no me aparece

Comment: deberia estar en la misma que el index.py o el html ? xq de ninguna de las 2 formas anda